# my jquery event handler for a button only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im making a sort of like social network website like twitter.
When the user wants to edit a post I open a div append a textarea, a "save" button and a "cancel" button with jquery.

But the cancel button only works once, the 2nd time the user clicks for editing a post, the cancel button doesn't work anymore.

```
$(function() 
{    
    function edit(chirp_id)
    {
        var div1 = $('<div></div>');
        div1.addClass('thumb2');
        div1.attr('id', chirp_id);
        $(div1).css('display','none');

        if($(div1).is(':visible'))
        {
            return;
        } 
        else
        {
            // Before the 'cancel' button I append the textarea and 'save' button

            var cancel = $('<button></button>');
            cancel.attr("id","cancelEdit");
            cancel.text("Cancel");

            cancel.addClass('button');
            cancel.appendTo(div2);

            $('#cancelEdit').click(function()
            {
                $(div1).fadeOut("slow");
            });
        }

        my_edit = edit;
     });
```

I call my function with javascript

```
function edit_chirp(chirp_id)
{
    my_edit(chirp_id);
}
```

Comment: Its just another div that contains the textarea and the 2 buttons.
div2 and appended to div1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .. bind event with dom not with ID ..

```
$(function () {

function edit(chirp_id) {
    var div1 = $('<div></div>');
    div1.addClass('thumb2');
    div1.attr('id', chirp_id);
    $(div1).css('display', 'none');

    if ($(div1).is(':visible')) {
        return;
    } else {
        //Before the 'cancel' button I append the textarea and the 'save' button
        var cancel = $('<button></button>');
        cancel.attr("id", "cancelEdit");
        cancel.text("Cancel");

        cancel.addClass('button');
        cancel.appendTo(div2);

        cancel.click(function () {
            $(div1).fadeOut("slow");
        });
    }
    my_edit = edit;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use `delegates` using **`.on`** event handler because your div1 is created dynamically

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancelEdit', function () {
                $(div1).fadeOut("slow");
            });
```

Missing to close `edit` function

Comment: And also look for a missing bracket closing your function on the first block posted.

Comment: I have tried using the delegates...it still only works once.
The 2nd time the cancel button doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

probably to do with closure. try:

```
cancel.click(function (event) {
    $(event.target).closest(".thumb2").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what can be causing this!